# Is there a way to forward sensitive headers on redirect using httpclient5 AsyncHttpClient

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-5.x

I'm trying to handle a redirect with a Spring WebClient, using an `org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.async.HttpAsyncClient` under the hood, and forward the sensitive headers in the redirect request. I see examples in previous versions that there is a way using a `.followRedirect(boolean followRedirect, Consumer<HttpClientRequest> redirectRequestConsumer)` configuration, but that doesn't appear to exist in the current version.

My alternative is to turn off following redirect, grab the headers and cookies in the redirect response, and then send off a second request with that information, but that seems like more of a hack than a proper solution.

Thanks!

Edit: This is what I ended up with based on the comments, which worked:

```
public static WebClient create(final boolean followRedirects) {
    final HttpAsyncClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpAsyncClientBuilder.create();
    final RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setRedirectsEnabled(followRedirects).build();
    clientBuilder.setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig);
    final ClientHttpConnector connector = new HttpComponentsClientHttpConnector(clientBuilder.build());
    return WebClient.builder().clientConnector(connector).build();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set it in the builder

[public RequestConfig.Builder setRedirectsEnabled(boolean redirectsEnabled)](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.1.x/current/httpclient5/apidocs/org/apache/hc/client5/http/config/RequestConfig.Builder.html#setRedirectsEnabled(boolean))

And [set your RequestConfig in your RequestBuilder](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.1.x/current/httpclient5/apidocs/org/apache/hc/client5/http/async/methods/SimpleRequestBuilder.html#setRequestConfig(org.apache.hc.client5.http.config.RequestConfig))

See also See [setRedirectStrategy](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.1.x/current/httpclient5/apidocs/org/apache/hc/client5/http/impl/async/HttpAsyncClientBuilder.html#setRedirectStrategy(org.apache.hc.client5.http.protocol.RedirectStrategy))

Comment: By default that doesn't forward the sensitive headers, does it? It's not what I'm seeing.

Comment: It looks to me like if forwards all the headers line 1080 of https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/current/httpclient/xref/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultRequestDirector.html

Comment: See also setRedirectStrategy.